# External Monitor being prioritized over Laptop monitor in Duplicated Screens

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have been messing around with settings on my computer recently, and I don't know what happened but when I changed the resolution in my NVIDIA control panel my external monitor suddenly became the primary monitor when using duplicated view. Is there any easy way to change which monitor is being used? It's a problem for me because whenever I use OBS it does not detect my external monitor, so I cannot record games while playing on duplicated from my external monitor anymore. I've been messing a lot with the NVIDIA control panel settings but nothing seems to work, and I have set my laptop monitor as the main monitor but it doesn't use it when I plug in the HDMI, it just shows the external monitor on the laptop screen in duplicated view. I appreciate any support, thank you!

Comment: You might want to post a screenshot of the utility you're using as there are literally more than 10 different iterations... and yes, there is a "Primary Monitor" setting.